# How to list of ave_rating based on PlaceID, take its average and assign to all the PlaceID's with PlaceID.?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis

This is the sample of my dataset (in image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIiq1.png)e), i need each unique placeID to have only one rated value by averaging all the ratings for each placeID, i tried doing it with python and pandas as lib but it doesn't work, help needed!!

  1.

---

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Uh, Sample Output?

Comment: 135085   - 2.7-  22.150802 -100.982680 - medium - Fast_Food i.e each  unique placeID to have only one rated average_value

Comment: you mean to say all the PlaceID with 135085 must have an ave_rating 2.7?

Comment: I mean to say all the PlaceID with 135085 must have an ave_rating of value that is the average  of all the rating 135085 has got, i.e 135085 - average of all the ratings recived for 135085 - 22.15-100.98-medium-fast food, have look at the data set

Comment: did u understand?

Comment: easy peasy, get a list of ave_rating based on PlaceID, take its average and assign to all the PlaceID's with PlaceID.

Comment: i am not able to get the list of ave_rating based on placeID, can you PlEASE help me with that code portion! please!!!

Comment: Can I have access to that data?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/121S4CihpR50c9sCNQ2bSHhoxjXo6wB9S/view?usp=sharing

Comment: bro, it has been done, thankyou to you too ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer below code. It will take the mean of ave_rating column.Here I have assumed that for each placeID: Latitude,longitude and Rcuisine value is same.

```
df.groupby(['placeID','latitude','longitude','price','Rcuisine']).mean()
```

Comment: plz vote up if it solves your problem ;)

Comment: i just checked, came to give you a thanks, it was so simple but i was overthink abt it so much, thankyou again ^.^